# How can I add xr.open_mfdataset output to an xarray dataset in Python?

Tags: python, merge, concatenation, dask, python-xarray

I'm hoping to get some help on an issue I've been struggling with for a couple of days!

I have 216 .nc files in a folder. These files are originally from a .nc files that included 216 time dimensions, but I needed to process separatly so I sliced the original dataset. I am now trying to reassemble the original .nc file with additional variables in each file.

I have tried concatenating all files but my laptop's RAM is too low (16 GB), meaning this crashes every time. I then found `xr.open_mfdataset` which successfully opens all 216 .nc files in my folder but each variable is a dask.array, for example:

`pH       (time, lon, lat, pres) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 360, 145, 58), meta=np.ndarray>`.

When I isolate a variable, I do get all expected dimensions, in the case of the variable above:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'pH' (time: 216, lon: 360, lat: 145, pres: 58)>
dask.array<concatenate, shape=(216, 360, 145, 58), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1, 360, 145, 58), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) float64 7.32e+05 7.32e+05 7.323e+05 ... 7.349e+05 7.35e+05
  * lon      (lon) float64 -179.5 -178.5 -177.5 -176.5 ... 177.5 178.5 179.5
  * lat      (lat) float64 -64.5 -63.5 -62.5 -61.5 -60.5 ... 76.5 77.5 78.5 79.5
  * pres     (pres) float64 2.5 10.0 20.0 30.0 ... 1.8e+03 1.9e+03 1.975e+03
```

However, once again, I'm not super familiar with Dask but it's not exactly an xr Data Array.

One idea then came to mind, which would be to add each variable to the original dataset (I only have a few variables so I don't mind doing it somewhat manually). I did trying a couple of things:

```
test = ds.assign(pH.values)
test = ds.merge(pH, join="outer")
test = xr.concat([ds, pH])
```

The computing time for one variable is okay (~2 minutes) so I think it is indeed adding the variable, however, I end up with the following irrespective of the line used above:

```
var    (time, pres, lat, lon) float32 8.044 7.858 7.869 ... nan nan nan
pH       (time, lon, lat, pres) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 360, 145, 58), meta=np.ndarray>
```

This means that 1. coordinates are in the wrong order and 2. I'm still dealing with dask while other variables are only in xarray. I don't really understand why coordinates aren't recognized in the process, and the new variable isn't being rearrange to match the dataset's structure.

Anyone knows how to deal with this type of problem? I just want to add the variable pH to my original dataset. Or to create a new dataset from the `xr.open_mfdataset` line. Final dimensions should be `Dimensions:  (time: 216, pres: 58, lat: 145, lon: 360)`.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: I’d read the docs on using xarray with dask. You can write the result of a dataset with dask variables just like normal. Just give it a whirl! If you want to convert it to a normal numpy-based DataArray you can call `ds = ds.compute()`.

Comment: As for adding it to the dataset - you’ve already successfully done this! It’s fine to have both dask and numpy-based variables in your dataset.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks for replying so fast - I’ll give a go to compute.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado But is it really okay if I add it and the dimensions aren’t in the same order? I also don’t know whether I could save the ds to an .nc file?

Comment: Yes and yes :) if you need them to be in the same order you could use  .transpose, though this may not be as efficient depending on the workflow. And I’d recommend zarr over netcdf because zarr supports parallel writes. But netcdf works just fine if you need to use it.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado that’s great to hear! One last question- would you recommend converting the entire ds to a Dask ds then? Is there an advantage in this situation? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Depends on what you’re doing with it. There is no reason why they both need to be dask.

Comment: If you’re planning to write to netcdf, I’d say no, don’t chunk the numpy array of it isn’t already chunked.

Comment: And there's no way to "dechunk" the dask array right?

Comment: Small update, I managed to save it an .nc file and once I load it it's not a dask array anymore but a beautiful consistent ds - thanks so much for your help, it was super useful clearing things up :)